# Port forwarding problem

Tags: java, android, port, forward

I'm currently developing java PC/Android application with server written in java. When I was developing PC client I was starting server on localhost:12345, and client could, without any problems, connect to this server (using the same host name and port). Problems started yesterday when I tried to connect using android device. I use my mobile phone to develop app and as a host address I input my router's public IP 89.xx.xx.xxx and the same port as in PC client (12345). Of course I set up port forwarding on my router (for ports 12344 to 12346 ), and I created rules for any connection type on port 12345 in windows defender. But still no success. This is weird because about 8 months before i was developing other app and everything just worked. Strange thing is that there was no windows prompt window when I started server and PC client for the first time (win defender prompt to allow my app to connect to the internet). I think that's something's wrong with the router's forwarding (because on localhost it works properly), but I do not know what else I can do. I turned ON UPnP beside forwarding. My router is THOMSON TWG850-4U. After a couple seconds I get timed-out exception in my android app

Comment: Have you verified whether you could connect to that server from outside using a regular PC (not your android app), just to make sure that the problem is not related to the mobile network the android device uses to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server is binding 0.0.0.0 (accept incoming connections on any interface) rather than 127.0.0.1 (only localhost connections accepted)?

Comment: I changed localhost to 0.0.0.0 (If that is what you meant) on server socket bind and still it can't connect

Answer (score 0):

If you are already binding to 0.0.0.0 then try setting your router to DMZ your PCs IP address and see if you are allowed to connect.

Comment: I tried this before but no difference. FYI I left port forwarding when I turned on DMZ and to connect I used routers public IP

Comment: if you are on the network when making these requests you should use the computers LAN IP not the routers public IP.